# django - get field which name is dynamic

Tags: python, django

What I need:
I want to get object details from DB. I use get() function. The problem I have is, that I make in in a function, and one of the arguments is field name as string:

```
def delete_file_if_changed(id, change, form, model, field_name='image'):
    if change:
        if field_name in form.changed_data:
            old_image = model.objects.get(pk__exact=id)
```

Now - how can I do the thing that I can get old_image.field_name - how to do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You know, I thought this was your answer at first -- it lets you search by a dynamic property: Could the `**` operator work?

```
kw = {field_name:change} # you're not explicit as to which is the field_name
                         # value you would like to search for.
old_image = model.objects.get(**kw)
```

But, if you already have the object you want, and you just need to get the value of a dynamically named property, then you can use [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(old_image, "id", "Spam") # gets old_image.id, if that does not exist, it
                                 # defaults to the str "Spam" Of course, in this 
                                 # context, you probably want 
                                 # getattr(old_image, field_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about `getattr(old_image, field_name)`? More info in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the field value, avoid the whole process of building out the model instance and getting the value, just query it directly from the database:

```
field_value = model.objects.values_list(field_name, flat=True).get(pk__exact=id)
```